# Create a database for web application. Keep primary key for tables

Tags: mysql, web-applications

I am developing a web application but I am pretty new to this.

Basic idea:
User logs in and can input data through many different forms. Each form should be connected to a user and catalogued by year and month.

Right now my database structure is:

```
core_user: id_user,username, password
core_year: id_year, year
core_month: id_month, month
ch: id_ch, many variables...
```

I would like to have columns in `core_year`, `core_month` and `ch` that register `id_user` so that I can retrieve and store data for the user and by month and year.

I've tried with foreign keys but had no success.

What I'd like to have:

```
task--> user registered--> unique primary key=id_user
task--> year registered--> unique primary key=id_year with the id_user of the
                                                      session that is going on.
```

and so on..

Any suggestion?

Comment: What does `ch` stand for?

Comment: Why do you want separate tables for year and month and not just a date field in the table that would have had the `core_year.id_year` and `core_month.id_month` foreign keys? Or you can leave it as year and month if you want, but without the extra tables, I suppose there may be one or two advantages to this as opposed to using a date.

Comment: What did you try with Foreign Keys and in what way was it not successful? This should not be a problem, but you haven't described the problem.